# Como formatar dados dentro de uma DIV(alinhamento e fonte)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, div, bootstrap-4

Preciso alinhar corretamente as informações dentro das divs a seguir, colocar a imagem a esquerda, o titulo em azul ao lado da imagem a direita e a temperatura logo abaixo do titulo em azul, como ilustra a segunda imagem 2 que editei da forma que pretendo que fique.

Imagem 1:
[image: Imagem 1]

Imagem:2
[image: Imagem 2]

codigo:

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2em
}

.interna {
  font: 150%/1.2 Arial;
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  /* Valor da Largura */
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background: #E8E8E8
}

#chart_div {
  font: 150%/1.5 Arial;
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10;
}

._margin-b-5 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

._block {
  display: block!important;
}

.-dark-blue {
  color: #004983!important;
}

.-bold {
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Monitoramento</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="api/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </script>
</head>
<div id="container">
  <div id="interna" class="interna col-xl m-5 pb-6 shadow-lg p-3 mb-4  rounded-sm border border-left-0 border-top-0">
    <img src='img/quente.png' width=30 height=60>
    <span class="_block _margin-b-5 -bold -dark-blue">Nobreak</span> 28.35º
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara tem vários detalhes no seu código, ele não esta bem formatado dentro dos critérios do Grid do Bootstrap que vc está usando... Mas para fazer o que vc quer basta colocar as classes nativas `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` na `div` com o `id` `interna`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Monitoramento</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="api/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </script>
  <style>
  #container {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2em
}

.interna {
  font: 150%/1.2 Arial;
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  /* Valor da Largura */
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background: #E8E8E8
}

#chart_div {
  font: 150%/1.5 Arial;
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10;
}

._margin-b-5 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

._block {
  display: block!important;
}

.-dark-blue {
  color: #004983!important;
}

.-bold {
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
}
  </style>
</head>
<div id="container">
  <div id="interna" class="interna col-xl m-5 pb-6 shadow-lg p-3 mb-4 rounded-sm border border-left-0 border-top-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src='img/quente.png' width=30 height=60>
    <span class="_block _margin-b-5 -bold -dark-blue">Nobreak</span> 28.35º
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Pois é, to aprendendo desenvolver web ainda, comecei agora a usar bootstrap e to meio confuso, aos poucos vou me familiarizando haha mas muito obrigado, me ajudou muito no que queria.

Comment: @Douglas isso ai, foca nos estudos, e se vc quiser mesmo seguir com o BS, leia e releia a documentação, ela é bem completa, e 90% das coisas da para fazer com as classes nativas. E principalmente, estude muito o GRID, ele é a base de turo, e vc coloca um col, como filha direta de um container não é indicado... vc pode ter problemas de responsividade se não seguir o grid corretamente. Bons estudos ai